# How can I use Get-TCPConnection and get more information about the processes? Precisely the Processes File Version?

Tags: powershell, process, port, version

The output from the cmdlet Get-TCPConnection does not include the file version and for academic purposes I need that information.

I have tried many scrips, they just don't provide this precise information.

Comment: Please provide the code that you have attempted. We troubleshoot code, not provide free samples.

Comment: I am currently looking for a way to mix  Get-NetworkStatistics (which I downloaded) with Get-Process -FileVersionInfo but the get-process retrieves for a specific file and I would like to have every process listed on Get-NetworkStatistics to have their fileversion info

Comment: Please provide the code that you have attempted. Saying you have downloaded some modules does not show us how you have used them or what results they returned.

Comment: Sir, I don't have a code. I was hoping someone would have one that could fit the title description. A script or command capable like Get-NetTCPConnection but with one more column retrieving the file version.

Comment: Yes, I have tried so many scripts, but I didn't save them because they didn't work, and after many error lines I would just start clean again in order to follow up what i was doing.

Comment: Please refer to the Help Centre regarding Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-NetworkStatistics-66057d71) is where you got the script from, I made minor adjustments. I am not going to post the whole script so I will only post the changes I made.

Line 130. Added `FileVersion` property at the end.

```
$properties = 'ComputerName','Protocol','LocalAddress','LocalPort','RemoteAddress','RemotePort','State','ProcessName','PID', 'Fileversion'
```

Line 144. Added `FileVersion` property at the end.

```
$processes = Get-Process -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction stop | select name, id, FileVersion
```

Line 302. Removed `-ExpandProperty` and added `Fileversion`

```
if($procName = $processes | Where {$_.id -eq $procId} | select name, FileVersion ){ }
```

Now for the finale, Line 362-373, adjusted how the PSObject was created to include our new changes.

```
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                                ComputerName = $Computer
                                PID = $procId
                                ProcessName = $procName.Name
                                Protocol = $proto
                                LocalAddress = $localAddress
                                LocalPort = $localPort
                                RemoteAddress =$remoteAddress
                                RemotePort = $remotePort
                                State = $status
                                FileVersion = $procName.FileVersion
                            } | Select-Object -Property $properties
```